# mkdir: omit leading pathname when creating multiple directories?

Tags: bash, shell, mkdir

I'm sure this question has been asked elsewhere but I can't seem to phrase it in a way that returns a useful Google result.

I am creating a dozen directories that all have the same root path and I don't want to have to `cd` into it to be able to make these directories. The current command looks like something like, which is awful and repetitive:

```
$ mkdir frontend/app/components/Home frontend/app/components/Profile \ 
  frontend/app/components/Post frontend/app/components/Comment
```

An ideal syntax would be something along the lines of:

```
$ mkdir frontend/app/components/{Home, Profile, Post, Comment}
```

Is there something like this already that I just haven't found? I don't want to have to run a `for` loop just to make a few directories.

Comment: The "duplicate" is incorrect. The question linked to is about `mkdir -p`, while this question is not (see comments on @anubhava's answer). Anyway, there's an answer and the OP is happy, that's the most important :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wish is granted :-).

`mkdir` doesn't know and doesn't have to, but shells like `bash` or `zsh` understand the syntax `{...,...,...}`.

Just remove the spaces from your "along the lines of" and it works:

```
mkdir frontend/app/components/{Home,Profile,Post,Comment}
```

The shell will expand it to

```
mkdir frontend/app/components/Home frontend/app/components/Profile frontend/app/components/Post frontend/app/components/Comment
```

Since it is done by the shell, it works with any command.

Comment: Ha! Looks like `bash` knows what it's doing. This even works with `touch`

```
touch app/components/{Home/index.js,ProfileShow/index.js,PostShow/index.js}
```

Comment: @samcorcos The whole point of doing these types of replacements in the shell is that it works consistently with **any** command, since they just see the expanded arguments.

Comment: @barmar That's good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Remove spaces around comma and use `-p` option:

```
mkdir -p frontend/app/components/{Home,Profile,Post,Comment}
```

Comment: The `-p` option isn't needed unless `frontend/app/components` doesn't exist already.

Comment: Yes that is right but `-p` is handy to suppress error for already existing directories as well.

Comment: Why would you want to suppress the error if the directories aren't supposed to exist yet. It seems like this option is totally unrelated to the question.

Comment: Yes a bit unrelated to the question. I just find it handy for the situation when say `Post` is already existing but remaining ones aren't